# Get Facebook likes count to Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using Chart.JS (chartjs.org) and I'd like to use facebook likes count as a data for my charts.

My pie chart is working ok like that:

```
<script>
    var pieData = [
            {
                value : 30,
                color : "#f04124"
            },
            {
                value : 70,
                color : "#fff"
            }

        ];

var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart_01").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);

</script>
```

I was trying something like that, but it's not working.

```
<script>
jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/mysiteforchartdata1?callback=?', function(data){
            var fb_count2 = data['likes'].toString();

            $('.facebook_likes').html(fb_count2);
});
jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/mysiteforchartdata2?callback=?', function(data){
            var fb_count2 = data['likes'].toString();

            $('.facebook_likes').html(fb_count2);
});

    var pieData = [
            {
                value : fb_count1,
                color : "#f04124"
            },
            {
                value : fb_count2,
                color : "#fff"
            }

        ];

var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart_01").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);

</script>
```

I'd be thankful for full code as I'm a newbie in javascript.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` works asynchronously, so when you're defining `pieData`, the variables `fb_count1` and `fb_count2` don't exist yet. You have to do the following:

```
$.when(
 jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/metallica?callback=?'),
 jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/ironmaiden?callback=?')
).then(function(data1, data2){
 fb_count1 = data1[0]['likes'];
 fb_count2 = data2[0]['likes'];

 console.log([fb_count1, fb_count2]); // you can see the variables are there

 var pieData = [
  {
   value : fb_count1,
   color : "#f04124"
  },
  {
   value : fb_count2,
   color : "#fff"
  }
 ];

 var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart_01").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
});
```

[`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is a convenient way to create a callback for multiple requests (or other deferred actions). If there's only one request, you can assign the callback normally:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/metallica?callback=?', function(data){
  // now you can do things with data
  // but remember that everything that operates on it should be here
})
// ... and not here
```